# How to pass operator's output in .expand() in airflow 2.5

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, dynamic-mapping

I am currently working with an operator that returns a *continuation token*. Considering that the operator is called `FrOperator` and I have a sensor that will take this operator's continuation token `FrSensor`.

Airflow doesn't seem to be passing the output when providing the `

```
expanded_froperator = FrOperator.partial(<FIXED_VALUES>).expand(<SOMETHING>)
expanded_frsensor = FrSensor.partial(<FIXED_VALUES>).expand(expanded_froperator.output)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

`expanded_froperator.output` seems to be returning a `None` value in Xcoms causing the dag to be skipped.

Comment: Without knowing the `FrOperator`: Have you tried using a keyword in `.expand()`? 


`expanded_froperator = FrOperator.partial(...).expand(my_mapped_parameter=<some list>)
FrSensor.partial(...).expand(my_mapped_parameter= expanded_froperator.output)
`

?

Comment: @TJaniF yes indeed :) still working on the problem. It might night be an Airflow issue. Once i fix it, i might drop the question

Comment: Yeah in that case the issue might lie somewhere within the FrOperator. Makes sense because if you don't use a keyword inside .expand you usually get a specific error telling you to do so :)

Comment: Looks like you have to pass it as `XComArg`: `FrSensor.partial(<FIXED_VALUES>).expand(XComArg(expanded_froperator))`
Take a look at the following link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-over-result-of-classic-operators